# How to setup a proxy VPN in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-vpn-service

I want to connect to an HTTP proxy like this `95.179.128.75:8080` and tunnel all phones like [ultrasurf app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.ultrasurf.mobile.ultrasurf&hl=en). I try to make a Vpn Service with these codes:

```
class MyVpnService : VpnService() {

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    Builder().setSession("MyVPNService")
        .addAddress("95.179.128.75:8080", 24)
        .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
        .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0).establish()

    return Service.START_STICKY
}

}
```

But it doesn't work and I didn't find any source for connection to the proxy. Can you help me???

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the above, would work

See this example VPN implementation for global proxy
[TunProxy](https://github.com/raise-isayan/TunProxy.git) that should give some idea